# How to disable dragging on vbox children components (SENCHA TOUCH 2)

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a container with the vbox layout, this container has one toolbar and 5 formPanels (each with a fieldset) as children, my problem is that each of these 5 formPanels seems to be draggable and that's something I don't want. I've tried several ways of disabling the ability to drag these elements but none of them worked so far... how can i achieve such a result ?

A few things I've tried so far to disable dragging (aside from doing similar stuff through my controller) :

```
draggable: false,
disableSelection: true,
locked: true
```

MyConfigView.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyConfigView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myConfigview',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch',
            fullscreen: true,
            animation: {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left',
                duration: 8000
            }
        },
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui: 'light',
            title: 'Ya',
            itemId: 'toolbarConfigView',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'back',
                text: 'Voltar',
                action: 'voltarConfigView',
                itemId: 'myConfigViewVoltarBt'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            itemId: 'fieldSetAssalto',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Ya',
                model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'mensagem',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            itemId: 'fieldSetIncendio',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Ya',
                model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'mensagem',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            itemId: 'fieldSetSequestro',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Ya',

                model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',


                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'mensagem',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            itemId: 'fieldSetEmedico',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Ya',

                model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',


                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'mensagem',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            itemId: 'fieldSetAcidente',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Ya',
                model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'mensagem',
                    label: 'Ya'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    text: 'Save'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean drag-to-scroll?

If yes, try:

```
scrollable: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation so I added some indicator attribute to elements which tells whether it is draggable or not and in `dragstart` event I check whether the target element is draggable or not, if not I stop dragging. My method looks something like this:

```
    moreOptionsPanel.element.on("dragstart", function(evt){
        var isdraggable = event.target.getAttribute("isdraggable");
        if(isdraggable == "false")
        {
                var draggable = moreOptionsPanel.draggableBehavior.getDraggable();
                draggable.isDragging = false;
        }
    });
```

You should be able to put `isdraggable : false` in your panels or if you have html you can put it as attribute and check. Basically you need to put some differentiator and `ondragstart` you can see if that element or any of its parent is draggable or not.